# Change port 8080 for jhipster app

Tags: jhipster

I have already specified port 8080 for my jhipster apps during the initialization of the apps at the beginning when creating them with `yo jhipster`.

Now, I would like to know how I can change the port 8080 so I can run several apps at the same time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

2 alternatives:

- Edit `.yo-rc.json` file, change or add serverPort property like `"serverPort": "8100",` then re-generate your app with `jhipster --with-entities` if you did not make many changes or use `jhipster upgrade --force` if you did.
- Change port value in `application*.yml` files and `proxy.conf.json`,and probably also in some docker files

Comment: If I want to change to default 80, why this is not possible? any idea? I got this output when I tried to configured port 80 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Undertow

Comment: Well, with so few details about the error, it's difficult to say but I would guess that you have already an application running on this port, have you checked with netstat? You should open your own question with details if you really want to get help.

Comment: @hizmarck The problem could be with your `spring-boot-starter-undertow` dependency located in pom.xml file. The problem may arise when you starting application from *.jar file. To avoid this you need to make *.jar file fully executable by adding `<scope>provided</scope>` in the `spring-boot-starter-undertow` dependency.
[link](https://www.jhipster.tech/production/)

Answer (score 1):

Im using visual code, with minimal added code from jhipster generated code.  Using jhipster monolithic app (although I have done it with micorservices as well).

I just do `command + shift + F` to search for all instance of `8080`.  This helps you search all your files for this instance.

Then chose all the ones with yml files yo-rc.json, serverPorts, procy.conf.json, docker files, webpackdev etc... that pertains to port 8080 and change them to 8181 or other port number.

Hope this helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

If can do it manual, you change 3 files

- application-*.yml : the server port
- proxy.conf.json
- webpack.dev.js

If you use docker for deploiement, you must change file in doker folder.

Answer (score 0):

in **.yo-rc.json** file, change serverPort property "serverPort": "8081",
then run **jhipster --with-entities**